# Декодировать строку ISO-8859-1 в UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, iconv

Есть **$string** которая содержит внутри:

```
Âàëåðèé Ìåëàäçå Îêåàí È Òðè Ðåêè (Feat. Âèà Ãðà)
```

Несмог декодировать её в **UTF-8** , чтобы было читабельно.

Нагуглил сайт, онлайн декодер. Он переводит нормально. Получается результат:

```
Валерий Меладзе Океан И Три Реки (Feat. Виа Гра)
```

Декодер на сайте также указывает кодировки, которые применялись для выполнения.

**ISO-8859-1** =>  **Windows-1251**

Пробывал все возможные варианты:

`iconv ('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $string);`

`iconv ('ISO-8859-1', 'Windows-1251', $string);`

`iconv ('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $string);`

также пробывал **utf8_encode()** функцию.. Безрезультатно. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Откуда вы берете эту строку и куда ее записываете? Сама строка у вас записана в Windows-1251, но отображается в ISO-8859-1

Comment: делаю выборку из таблицы мускуля. В мускуле она записана точно также как и здесь. В мускуль пишется через сервис написанный на Go, который стучится к url-потоку http://listen15.vdfm.ru:8000/dacha и получает метаданные.

Comment: В таблице она хранится о кодировке поля, скорее всего как utf8, utf8mb4.

Comment: Как все усложнилось. Покажите кодировку этого поля в базе и с какой кодировкой подключаетесь к базе вы и сервис на Go?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, в базе кодировка поля `utf8_general_ci`. Подключаюсь к бд через phpmyadmin (это сопоставление кодировки соединения? тогда `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`).

Comment: @Anton покажите, как достаёте данные из БД(логин и пароль сотрите). Задаёте ли при сохранении параметры `mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");` И так далее.  И обязательно поможем.

Answer (score -1):

Как-бы Iconv и utf8_encode уже морально устарели.

Активный способ использовать **mb_convert_encoding** : https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

> Вообще очень советую изучить документацию на multybyte strings.

Для правельной конверсии надо пройти : CP1251 -> UTF8

ISO-8859-1 и CP1251 однобайтовые кодировки, изначально читай как CP1251.

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding($string, 'ISO-8859-1', 'CP1251');`
потом `mb_convert_encoding($string, 'CP1251', 'UTF-8');` так?

Comment: Это вообще зависит от очень многих факторов по сути.
1) В какой кодировке храниться поле в БД, узнать можно через SHOW CREATE TABLE. 2) В какой кодировке присоеденяется PHP к MySQL.

Наилучшыий способ это указать при соеденении кодировку UTF-8 и потом прогнать через.
UTF8->ISO-8859-1     после эту-же строку   'CP1251' -> 'UTF-8'

Следует брать во внимание что  ISO-8859-1 и CP1251 однобайтывые кодировки то-есть 1 символ = 1 байт! А UTF-8 (2 символа), UTF-8mb4 (2-4 символа), UTF-16 (2 символа), UTF-32 (2-4(+n2) символа) мультибайтовые = 1 буква соответственно.